# django post_save signals on update

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-signals

I am trying to set up some `post_save` receivers similar to the following:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Game, dispatch_uid='game_updated')
def game_updated(sender, **kwargs):

    '''DO SOME STUFF HERE'''

    MyPick.objects.filter(week=game.week, team=game.home_team).update(result=home_result)
    MyPick.objects.filter(week=game.week, team=game.away_team).update(result=away_result)


@receiver(post_save, sender=MyPick, dispatch_uid='user_pick_updated')
def update_standings(sender, **kwargs):
    '''DO STUFF'''
```

The first receiver is getting called correctly after an update on the Game object, however the calls to update on the MyPick object are not causing the second receiver to be called.  Does the post_save signal not work on update or am I missing something else here?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

[`update()` is converted directly to an SQL statement](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once); it doesn't call `save()` on the model instances, and so the `pre_save` and `post_save` signals aren't emitted. If you want your signal receivers to be called, you should loop over the queryset, and for each model instance, make your changes and call `save()` yourself.

Comment: @SilverLight, the `update` method on model instances emits `pre_save`. The `update` method on querysets doesn't.

Comment: Just to be clear then: Does the `update` method on a model instance emit `post_save` too, or only `pre_save`?

Comment: what about approach like this https://coderwall.com/p/rcmycw/django-sending-update-signal

Comment: but... what make me wonder... `update_or_create` fires `post_save` signal.

Comment: Because there is a `save` in the `update_or_create` method. But not in the `update` method. https://github.com/django/django/blob/4f128fcf5dd5099a5ea374a87cad64852a9b62dd/django/db/models/query.py#L613

Comment: @IsmailBadawi There is no `update` on a model instance.

Answer (score 50):

Just one more thing to @Ismali Badawi's answer.

---

This **calls** `post_save`

```
user = User.objects.get(id=1) 
user.username='edited_username' 
user.save()
```

This **does not call** `post_save`

```
User.objects.filter(id=1).update(username='edited_username')
```

---

In the code,

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def do_something_when_user_updated(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if not created:
        # User object updated
        user_obj = instance
        pass
```

Comment: Why it is not `if created:` instead?

Comment: @EliasPrado Because the function wants to do something when the user object is updated, not when the object is created.