# Django AuditTrail Update

Tags: django, audit

I want to audit one of my models with [AuditTrail](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/AuditTrail). But in some places of project I have such code :

```
q = Transaction.objects.filter(id = self.id).update(summa = self.summa)
```

Will Audit trail work whith this code or it works only on `model.save()`?

Answer (score 0):

A little late answer but better late than never for completeness:

As can be seen in the AuditTrail source code, the connection of the AuditTrail with the model is through the post_save signal

`models.signals.post_save.connect(_audit, sender=cls, weak=False)`

(so there is no relation with database triggers that'd do automatic inserts etc).

Also, as can be seen in @isbadawi's answer here

[django post_save signals on update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7375875/django-post-save-signals-on-update)

the post_save signal is fired only on save(). So, the answer is that AuditTrail will not work on your case (queryset update) :)