# django update_or_create(), see what got updated

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

My django app uses `update_or_create()` to update a bunch of records. In some cases, updates are really few within a ton of records, and it would be nice to know *what* got updated within those records. Is it possible to know what got updated (i.e fields whose values got changed)? If not, does any one has ideas of workarounds to achieve that?

This will be invoked from the shell, so ideally it would be nice to be prompted for confirmation just before a value is being *changed* within `update_or_create()`, but if not that, knowing what got changed will also help.

**Update (more context):** Thought I'd give more context here. The data in this Django app gets updated through various means (through users coming on the web site, through the admin page, through scripts (run from the shell) that populate data from a csv etc.). The above question is important mostly for the shell scripts that update data from csvs, hence a solution at the database/trigger/signal level may not be helpful here (I guess).

Comment: Actually, I think I figured something out by using a combination of get_or_create() and update_or_create(). May come back to post code here later.

Comment: @e4c5 I got it to work and wrote the code that worked for me, below on May 4th (and accepted it). Please let me know if you were expecting me to follow any specific guideline that I missed in that help document - thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing:

```
for row in reader:
    school_obj0, created = Org.objects.get_or_create(school_id = row[0])

    if (school_obj0.name != row[1]):
        print (school_obj0.name, '==>', row[1])
        confirmation = input('proceed? [y/n]: ')
        if (confirmation == 'y'):
                school_obj1, created = Org.objects.update_or_create(
                                school_id = row[0], defaults={"name": row[1],})
```

Happy to know about improvements to this approach (please see the update in the question with more context)

Comment: the `_or_create` may seem redundant here but this is a simplified version of my code. I may not have the `get_or_create()` or the confirmation-before-update in every case.

Answer (score 0):

> This will be invoked from the shell, so ideally it would be nice to be
>   prompted for confirmation just before a value is being changed

Unfortunately, databases don't work like that. It's the responsibility of applications to provide this functionality. And django isn't an application. You can however use django to write an application that provides this functionality.

As for finding out whether an object was updated or created, that's what the [return value](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.update_or_create) gives you. A tuple where the second value is a flag for update or create

Comment: Yes, the app is written using django. My question was, if I could track the change from some logic in the app itself. 
The return value tells me whether it got updated or created. I need to know _what_ got updated/changed (and ideally a prompt to confirm before changing it). I think I figured something out using a combination of get_or_create and update_or_create. May come back to post the code if it works.

Comment: neither update_or_create or get_or_create will tell you what fields got updated. You need to compare with the previous value for that. Which is best done by using a trigger.

Comment: Do you mean a database trigger? Correct me if wrong, but that would be after the update and not before? I need a confirmation from the user before the update. I am using `get_or_create()` (or just `get()`) to get the model object, then compare the old value with the new value. If different, get a confirmation and then update.

Comment: As I said, you can't prompt the user. with either of those functions. You will have to write your own replacement code for these functions if you want to prompt the user.

Comment: Also please note that triggers exists in all kinds of forms. befre update, after update, before delete, after delete .....

Comment: I agree for using signals. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7375875/django-post-save-signals-on-update

Comment: @e4c5 I meant the following sequence: (1) use Django's `get_or_create()` (2) write my code to compare values (3) prompt the user if needed (4) use Django's `update()` to update if confirmed by the user. 
Good to know about the `before update` trigger. I'll check it out. Thanks.