# Django models - Able to dynamically calculate the value of a field

Tags: python, django, django-models

Say for example I have a rating which is attached to a product model like so..

```
class Product(models.Model):
    ...
    rating = models.IntegerField(...)
```

I want the product rating to change as new Reviews (that include a star rating of the product) change or updated/deleted.

```
class Review(models.Model):
    ...
    related_product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, ...)
    rating = models.IntegerField(...)
```

Initially, I used a method on the product class to calculate the value of rating by counting the rating value from each review and then dividing by the number of reviews to get an average.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    ...
    def rating(self):
        total_rating = ...
        reviews_count = ...
        average = total_rating / reviews_count
```

However, this doesn't allow me to use order_by('rating') when querying the objects and sending back the objects by order of their rating since 'rating' has to be defined in the database (i.e. as a field instead of a method).

Is there any way that I can calculate the value for rating which is then stored in the database?

Comment: Depends very much on the calculation of `total_rating` and `revies_count`..

Comment: This is your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7375875/django-post-save-signals-on-update you need `post_save` signals

Answer (score 0):

You can annotate your queryset to calculate the average using your database

```
from django.db.models import Avg

Product.objects.all().annotate(
    rating=Avg('review_set__rating')
).order_by('rating')
```

Now each `Product` object in the queryset will have an additional attribute `rating`

If you must store this rating because it becomes expensive to calculate then @niklas' comment is the correct solution