# Possibly to nullify if not in django choices

Tags: python, django

Let's say I have the following django field:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):

    MONTH_CHOICES = [(str(i), calendar.month_name[i]) for i in range(1,13)]
    month = models.CharField(max_length=9, choices=MONTH_CHOICES, default='1')
```

Let's say someone enters in `40`, instead of it raising an error, I want it to just save it as `None` / `NULL`. Is there a way to do this, perhaps on the `save` method in a generic way?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean

Comment: @VishalSingh clean is for form validation, no? This is on a db insert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to set the `month` field to `Null`, you must set **`null=True`** in the Django model and must migrate the changes

```
month = models.CharField(
    max_length=9,
    choices=MONTH_CHOICES,
    default='1',
    null=True
)
```

and then, override the **`save(...)`** method of your model as,

```
def save(self, **kwargs):
    if not self.pk and not 1 <= int(self.month) <= 12:
        self.month = None
    super().save(**kwargs)
```

**Complte Example**

```py
class MyModel(models.Model):
    MONTH_CHOICES = [(str(i), calendar.month_name[i]) for i in range(1, 13)]
    month = models.CharField(
        max_length=9,
        choices=MONTH_CHOICES,
        default='1',
        null=True
    )

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk and not 1 <= int(self.month) <= 12:
            self.month = None
        super().save(**kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to add a null value for the model and must migrate the changes:

```
month = models.CharField(..., null=True)
```

You can use the clean method to validate your model and replace the data:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):

    ...

    def clean(self):
        if self.month not in self.MONTH_CHOICES:
            self.month = None
        return
```

**Or you can use pre_save signal** ([more](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/signals/))

```
 django.db.models.signals.pre_save
 from django.dispatch import receiver

 @receiver(pre_save, sender=MyModel)
 def my_callback(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
     if instance.month not in instance.MONTH_CHOICES:
        instance.month = None
```

Comment: Does a pre_save signal fire before a `Modal.objects.update(...)` or just on a save?

Comment: @David542 take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7375875/django-post-save-signals-on-update